# repmgrd and supervisord on docker - losing parent?

Tags: docker, supervisord, repmgr

I've created a Docker image with `PostgreSQL` and `repmgrd`, all launched with `supervisor`.

My problem now is that when it's launched, the `repmgrd` spawned by `supervisor` seems to kind of die and another one is in its place. This leads to my inability to control it using `supervisorctl` and instead having to resolve to `pkill` or similar to manage it.

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM postgres:10

RUN apt-get -qq update && \
    apt-get -qq install -y \
        apt-transport-https \
        lsb-release \
        openssh-server \
        postgresql-10-repmgr \
        rsync \
        supervisor > /dev/null && \
    apt-get -qq autoremove -y && \
    apt-get -qq clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# public keys configuration for passwordless login
COPY ssh/ /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/
# postgres, sshd, supervisor and repmgr configuration
COPY etc/ /etc/
# helper scripts and entrypoint
COPY helpers/ /usr/local/bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/pg-docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

The `pg-docker-entrypoint.sh` does little more than launching `supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`.

*supervisord.conf*

```
[unix_http_server]
file = /var/run/supervisor.sock
chmod = 0770
chown = root:postgres

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl = unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock

[supervisord]
logfile = /var/log/supervisor/supervisor.log
childlogdir = /var/log/supervisor
pidfile = /var/run/supervisord.pid
nodaemon = true

[program:sshd]
command = /usr/sbin/sshd -D -e
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/sshd-stdout.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/sshd-stderr.log

[program:postgres]
command = /docker-entrypoint.sh postgres -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/postgres-stdout.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/postgres-stderr.log

[program:repmgrd]
command = bash -c "sleep 10 && /usr/local/bin/repmgr_helper.sh"
user = postgres
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/repmgr-stdout.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/repmgr-stderr.log

[group:jm]
programs = sshd, postgres, repmgrd
```

The `repmgr_helper.sh` little more than `/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/repmgrd --verbose`.

*repmgr.conf*

```
node_id=1
node_name='pg-dock-1'
conninfo='host=pg-dock-1 port=5432 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=60'
data_directory='/var/lib/postgresql/data/'

use_replication_slots=1
pg_bindir='/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/'
failover='automatic'
promote_command='/usr/bin/repmgr standby promote --log-to-file'
follow_command='/usr/bin/repmgr standby follow --log-to-file -W --upstream-node-id=%n'
```

`ps` output

```sh
root@9f39cb085506:/# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 11:54 ?        00:00:00 bash /usr/local/bin/pg-docker-entrypoint.sh
root        10     1  0 11:54 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
root        13    10  0 11:54 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D -e
postgres    15    10  0 11:54 ?        00:00:07 postgres -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
postgres    36    15  0 11:54 ?        00:00:00 postgres: checkpointer process
postgres    37    15  0 11:54 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process
postgres    38    15  0 11:54 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process
postgres    39    15  0 11:54 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
postgres    40    15  0 11:54 ?        00:00:00 postgres: archiver process
postgres    41    15  0 11:54 ?        00:00:01 postgres: stats collector process
postgres    42    15  0 11:54 ?        00:00:00 postgres: bgworker: logical replication launcher
postgres    51    15  0 11:54 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal sender process repmgr 10.0.14.4(33812) streaming 0/4002110
postgres    55    15  0 11:54 ?        00:00:00 postgres: repmgr repmgr 10.0.14.4(33824) idle
postgres    88    15  0 11:54 ?        00:00:01 postgres: repmgr repmgr 10.0.14.5(33496) idle
postgres    90     1  0 11:54 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/repmgrd --verbose
root       107     0  0 11:54 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
root      9323   107  0 12:50 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

As you can see, the `repmgrd` process is now child of the entrypoint instead of `supervisor` (like `sshd` and `postgres`). I've tried to launch the command directly (no "helper"), I've tried using `bash -c`, I've tried specifying `/usr/bin/repmgrd` as executable, but no matter what I try in the end I always come to this result.

My question is then two-fold: why does this happen and what can I do to keep the `repmgrd` process under `supervisor`'s control.

---

**Edit**: As suggested I tried with `--daemonize=false` when starting repmgrd.

This kind of helps, but not completely. See the output:

```sh
root@6ab09e13f425:/# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 bash /usr/local/bin/pg-docker-entrypoint.sh
root        11     1  2 17:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
root        14    11  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D -e
postgres    15    11  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 bash /usr/local/bin/repmgr_helper.sh
postgres    16    11  1 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
postgres    37    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: checkpointer process
postgres    38    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process
postgres    39    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process
postgres    40    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
postgres    41    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: archiver process
postgres    42    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector process
postgres    43    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: bgworker: logical replication launcher
postgres    44    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal sender process repmgr 10.0.23.136(47132) streaming 0/4008E28
root        45     0  0 17:06 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
postgres    77    15  1 17:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/repmgrd --daemonize=false --verbose
postgres    78    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: repmgr repmgr 10.0.23.136(47150) idle
postgres    79    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: repmgr repmgr 10.0.23.134(43476) idle
root        86    45  0 17:06 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
root@6ab09e13f425:/# supervisorctl stop jm:repmgrd
jm:repmgrd: stopped
root@6ab09e13f425:/# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 bash /usr/local/bin/pg-docker-entrypoint.sh
root        11     1  1 17:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
root        14    11  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D -e
postgres    16    11  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
postgres    37    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: checkpointer process
postgres    38    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process
postgres    39    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process
postgres    40    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
postgres    41    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: archiver process
postgres    42    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector process
postgres    43    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: bgworker: logical replication launcher
postgres    44    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal sender process repmgr 10.0.23.136(47132) streaming 0/4008E60
root        45     0  0 17:06 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
postgres    77     1  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/repmgrd --daemonize=false --verbose
postgres    78    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: repmgr repmgr 10.0.23.136(47150) idle
postgres    79    16  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 postgres: repmgr repmgr 10.0.23.134(43476) idle
root       106    45  0 17:07 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

At startup the process remains with `supervisor`, but stopping it will only kill the `repmgr_helper.sh` leading to the "real" process to remain alive and be reassigned to `1` as its parent.

This isn't ideal because now I have a weird situation where the process is alive, but `supervisor` thinks it's not. Hence issuing a `supervisorctl start jm:repmgrd` wil fail saying

```
[ERROR] PID file "/tmp/repmgrd.pid" exists and seems to contain a valid PID
[HINT] if repmgrd is no longer alive, remove the file and restart repmgrd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer based on the discussion in the comments:**

These are the issues with the current solution:

1. The original command to start repmgrd:

   `command = bash -c "sleep 10 && /usr/local/bin/repmgr_helper.sh"`

   runs bash, which executes another bash script (that is another instance of bash), which then runs repmgrd, these are too many processes, most of them not needed
2. supervisord wants that the invoked command remains in the foreground, but repmgrd by default daemonizes itself
3. While troubleshooting there were some issues with the pid file generated by repmgrd

These can be fixed by the following changes:

1. The command to be used instead:

   `command = /usr/local/bin/repmgr_helper.sh`
2. `/usr/local/bin/repmgr_helper.sh` needs to be updated to run `sleep 10` as the first step
3. `/usr/local/bin/repmgr_helper.sh` as the very last step should invoke repmgrd the following way:

   `exec /path/to/repmgrd --daemonize=false --no-pid-file`

   so, a. due to the `exec` it replaces the script it starts it b. it doesn't daemonize itself c. it doesn't generate a pid file.

**Original answer (before the updates)**

In the start command try passing `--daemonize=false` to repmgrd.

Comment: I tried, but it's not working completely. See my edit, please

Comment: The pid file may have remained there from a previous run, as the message suggests you could just remove it before starting the process again. Also it would possibly help if you also passed `--no-pid-file` to the start command, so it wouldn't deal with the pid file at all.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. I believe that supervisor stopped the helper process, but the actual repmgrd stays alive. I could tell it not to use the pid file, but that wouldn't change the situation, would it?

Comment: ok, instead of ```command = bash -c "sleep 10 && /usr/local/bin/repmgr_helper.sh"``` 1. just change this to ```command = /usr/local/bin/repmgr_helper.sh```, 2. change repmgr_helper.sh to `sleep 10; exec /path/to/repmgrd --daemonize=false --no-pid-file`. This way the script will be replaced (due to the "exec") by repmgrd so there would be only one process to be tracked by supervisord. Don't worry about the --no-pid-file, it doesn't matter much.

Comment: with `exec` works like a charm, thanks! may i suggest you edit your answer to include the actual solution, for those who come looking next?